# Get "type" of DCG in Prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I have a college assignment that asks me to return the "type" of a certain phrase built by a DCG.
I will give you and example because I know calling it the "type" isnt the most correct.

```
greetings-->sn(N,M),sv(N,M).
sn(N,M)--> greet(N,M).
greet(sing,male)--> [bom].
greet(sing,female)--> [boa].
greet(plur,male)--> [bons].
greet(plur,female)--> [boas].
```

(For those who asking this DCG is for portuguese)
I need to do a predicate that receives for example "bom" and should return "greet". Given a word I need to return his "type" in the DCG. The teacher explained the basics of DCGs so I dont know how to even do a predicate that "searches" in a DCG.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you want this to behave? What would a valid query look like and results?

Comment: Example getType("bom", X) and the output should be something like "X = "greet"".

Comment: Ok, interesting. Is `greet` the "type"?

Comment: Yes, I dont know what to call it so I call it the "type".

Comment: You could make the sentence type one of the arguments. `sn(N, M) --> sentence(greet, N, M).`, `sentence(greet, sing, male) --> [bom].`, etc...

Comment: I tried that but still how could I do a predicate that would return "greet"? Im new to prolog and teacher teaches basics and asks for advanced stuff :/

Comment: You pass a variable for the "type". I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but if you need "greet" to come back from `sn` and `greetings`, you just need to add the variable: `greetings(Type) --> sn(Type, N, M), sv(N, M).` and `sn(Type, N, M) --> sentence(Type, N, M).`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204430/discussion-between-hugo-dias-and-lurker).